# ValueError when returning z-value from contour

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, interpolation, spline

I am trying to return the `z-value` of a contour. The specific point I want to use to return the `z-value` is called from `['C1_X'],['C1_Y']` in the `df`. The code works when these coordinates are in ascending order but it throws an error when in descending order.

Error:

```
raise ValueError("Error code returned by bispev: %s" % ier)
ValueError: Error code returned by bispev: 10
```

The code used to return the z-value is:

```
    # Return z-value for C coordinate
    f = RectBivariateSpline(X[0, :], Y[:, 0], normPDF.T)
    z = f(d['C1_X'], d['C1_Y']) 
    print(z)
```

Comment: Did you google your error? http://www.netlib.org/dierckx/bispev.f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error code 10 means that input is invalid (Google search!).

Create toy data. Your code is doing a lot of things and I would like to isolate the part that causes error.

```py
X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, 20), np.linspace(0, 20))
```

Create a callable to interpolate values at input.

```py
from scipy.interpolate import RectBivariateSpline
f = RectBivariateSpline(X[0, :], Y[:, 0], z = X**2+Y**2)
```

Try to run code.

```py
f([10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10], [10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,9])
```

Truncated output

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-84-73aaa29ad73f> in <module>
----> 1 f([10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10], [10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,9])
```

Check the docstring of `f` to see if there is some information there. I am doing this in a Jupyter notebook.

```py
f?
```

Truncated output

```
Signature:      f(x, y, dx=0, dy=0, grid=True)
Type:           RectBivariateSpline
String form:    <scipy.interpolate.fitpack2.RectBivariateSpline object at 0x7f5a4a7f9cc0>
File:           ~/bin/anaconda3/envs/py37a/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/fitpack2.py
Docstring:     
Bivariate spline approximation over a rectangular mesh.

Can be used for both smoothing and interpolating data.

Parameters
----------
x,y : array_like
    1-D arrays of coordinates in strictly ascending order.
...
...
...
```

Oh. It wants the points to be evaluated at also in **strictly ascending order**. So will ordering the points to be evaluated work?

```py
f([10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10], [9, 10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10])
```

Output

```
array([[181., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200.],
       [181., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200.],
       [181., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200.],
       [181., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200.],
       [181., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200.],
       [181., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200.],
       [181., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200.],
       [181., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200.],
       [181., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200.],
       [181., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200., 200.]])
```

Will sorting the points at which the interpolations are to be performed before calling the interpolation function work in your code work?

Hope this helps.

---

**EDIT**

Here is what I mean:

```py
f = RectBivariateSpline(X[0, :], Y[:, 0], normPDF.T)
# z = f(d['C1_X'], d['C1_Y'])
x_ip = d['C1_X']
y_ip = d['C1_Y']
z = np.empty((len(x_ip), len(y_ip)), dtype=np.float64)
for i, x in enumerate(x_ip):
    z[i, :] = f([x], y_ip) # ASSUME THAT y_ip IS SORTED.
print(z)
```

I got your code running on my machine with this change: it shows some animation of contours. Adapt this idea to other situations where x and y can't be both in ascending order. You could loop over both x and y but that will increase the number of function calls.

Comment: Thanks @Prasanath. It appears that the error will occur is any of the `X` or `Y` coordinate descends. If it was just one I could sort it. This might have to be a stopgap though.

Comment: If performance is not of concern then perhaps calling `f` with points one by one is a possibility?

Comment: Is there a method to iterate one frame at a time?

Comment: I am referring to the expression `z = f(d['C1_X'], d['C1_Y']) ` . You can perhaps do `z = np.empty(...)` and then fill in values by looping over `zip(d['C1_X'], d['C1_Y'])`. Try it and see if code runs too slow!

Comment: Like this:     `f = RectBivariateSpline(X[0, :], Y[:, 0], normPDF.T)
    z = f(d1['C1_X'], d1['C1_Y']) 
    z = np.empty(f(d1['C1_X'], d1['C1_Y']))
    z = zip(d['C1_X'], d['C1_Y'])
    print(z)`

Comment: Use `empty` to create an empty array of the same dimension as `z`. Then loop over the points at which you want to call `f` and assign the result from `f` to the appropriate location in `z`. `zip(...)` may or may not be the solution here --- idea is to call `f` at each location one by one, instead of passing in the whole x and y locations,  since sorting the input to `f` seems not possible here.